# Unity build stuck on Scene 0

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

My Unity game stuck during build (For Android) on Scene 0. I looked into the Editor log but it didnt show any error, it just stopped logging like 5 lines after loading Scene 0 (Which are just lines about loading objects which is says was completed). I tried fixing it by unchecking bake global illumination and autogenerate lightmap options (As I read here on this site). The problem began appearing after I began using custom mainTemplate.gradle and androidmanifest.xml. After I atopped using it, it didnt go away. I havent fixed this so far, thank you for any answer in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it's stuck and not just taking a *really* long time?

Comment: Just so you know. It can take an insane amount of time depending on many factors. So. A simple scene with like 4 short scripts my home pc. Took about 6 mins. My work pc to do the same was 10 HOURS.   Sometimes you just have to leave it doing it’s thing.

Comment: I am sure its stuck. This happens in every scene I choose to build (When I uncheck one and check the other) and the build usually takes just 5 minutes (At most) and this particular scene wasnt ever building for so long

Answer (score 0):

Disable the 'Enable Resolution on Build' in Android Resolver Settings from the External Dependency Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this same problem by applying this setting to my Android Resolver Settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by unchecking "Use Jetifier" in...

For Windows users:
Assets -> External Dependency Manager -> Android Resolver -> Settings